# DataGrid edit doesn't change the actual source

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` (Points) bound to a `DataGrid`. I don't know if this is not normal, but the changes that I make editing the cells (my points) doesn't actually change my collection, but just the view.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="s1Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding s1Puntos, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="165" 
                          Background="#19B0C4DE" BorderThickness="1"
                          BorderBrush="#19D3D3D3" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                          CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                          ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" CellEditEnding="s1Grid_CellEditEnding">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=X, StringFormat='{}    {0:#.00}', Mode=TwoWay}"  Header="X" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Y, StringFormat='{}    {0:#.00}', Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Y" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>    
</DataGrid>
```

Do you see something wrong?

Note: `s1Grid_CellEditEnding` is an event that sends a message to update something using that collection.

Comment: Are you getting any binding errors in output window

Comment: did you try `{Binding ... UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and it was the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Binding **UpadateSourceTrigge=PropertyChanged**.

This is used whenever you need to send the changes from Your **View** to the **ViewModel**.As in this case you are editing your collection in view and want to reflect back into your **collection** You need to use **UpdateSourceTrigger** Property.

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried that and no result. I think the problem could be that I'm binding to an ObservableCollection of "Struct" Point, and you can't change a Struct, please, correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Point` is a `struct` which means that when you bind `ItemsSource`, control will enumerate your source collection to create `Items` which for `struct`, and any other value type, means create a copy. Long story short, `DataGrid` is changing `Point` item but only it's own copy.